Delete old JMS messages from queue using Apache Camel timer
Want to write a timer job to delete 5 min old message from a queue. It should delete only 5 min old messages not others. It should pick all message in one go.
I try pollInRich but it pick only one message at a time
I tried:
from("timer:deleteExpiredMessagesTimer?period=60000") // Trigger every hour (3600000 milliseconds)
            .process(exchange -> {
              from("activemq:queue:esbShipComplete.zufo.heartbeat?selector=JMSTimestamp < " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - 300000))
                      .to("log: Deleted expired history messages.");
            });

but it run only once while restarting application.
I tried to put timeToLive parameter when sending each message, but that moves message to DLQ after expiry which I don't want.

What version of Apache Camel are you using?
